# What is the German word or phrase for "village returning to forest"?

Tags: single-word-request

I read once that there is a German word (or perhaps phrase), that developed during the Black Death, for a village that is "*returning to the forest*". Certainly the devastation suffered at that time by Germany (or more properly the Holy Roman Empire), combined with its low population density and high forest cover, makes the existence of such a word believable.

Can anyone identify this word for me?

Answer (score 25):

The German Wikipedia article on Black Death (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzer_Tod) mentions the word *Wüstung*:

> Unrentabel gewordene Grenzböden wurden aufgegeben, was in manchen Regionen dazu führte, dass Dörfer verlassen oder nicht mehr wiederbesiedelt wurden (sogenannte Wüstungen), die im Hochmittelalter im Zuge des Landesausbaus abgeholzten Wälder breiteten sich wieder aus.

This mentions that these villages have often be reconquered by the forest.

Wikipedia also has an article on the lemma *Wüstung* ([https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wüstung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%BCstung)) which clarifies that this is not referring specifically to abandoned villages which have been taken back by the forest, but more unspecifically to any abandoned settlement.

I am not sure if there is a more specific notion which also indicates that the village has been reconquered by the forest.

The word *Wüstung* is derived from the adjective *wüst* which means *empty, desert, waste* and also *rough*, of characters also *uncivilized*. The German word *Wüste* (*desert*) also stems from this adjective.

There is also a verb for becoming a *Wüstung* which is *wüstfallen*, which is also used in the Wikipedia article on *Wüstung*.

Comment: Also note the adjective *wüst*. *Es war eine wüste Rauferei.* → no limits.

Comment: While Wüstung is the correct word, 90% of Germans have probably never heard of it, so depending on what you're writing, you might want to explain it. And, please don't try to make a verb/adjective out of it, verwüsten/verwüsted always refers to a deliberate action or natural disaster, not a slow returning to nature.

Comment: So, `Wüstung` is basically `wasteland`?

Answer (score 15):

> Die Natur holt sich das Dorf zurück

is certainly a possible translation though it feels as if a more specific, historical term is what you are after :)

Answer (score 11):

There was not one word for this, but at least five, counting sticklish the spelling variations and regionalisms the number is even bigger.

## What *was* the word for …

The historical term applied to 'villages abandoned' for the time of the Black Death is certainly indeed *Wüstung*. But that is more for ghost-towns and says not much about the type of nature taking hold within them, although in Germany that would certainly be some type of forest eventually.

*Wüstung* just means strictly that the villagers deserted their homes and only implies the disrepair and wildlife following. The place itself is a *Wüstung* but the process of "villages returning to forest” is not captured well in that word.

> [**Wüstung**](https://www.spektrum.de/lexikon/geographie/wuestung/9167) –
>   Wüstung, aufgegebene Siedlung,
>   <sub>–– Lexikon Der Geographie</sub>

So now the *process* is depicted in ***Wüstungsprozess, Wüstungsbildung.***

While still in use now, historically this word also had a few synonyms:

> **Wüstung, Wüste, Wüsteney, Laide, Lehde**
>
> So nennt man insgemein unbearbeitete Felder, die mit Holz angeflogen, oder mit Gebüsche bewachsen, und vorhin gebauet Feld gewesen sind. Wüstungen fallen dem Fisco anheim, und mögen von dem Landes= oder Grund=Herrn eingezogen und andern verliehen werden.
>   <sub>–– Johann Heinrich Zedler: "Grosses Universal-Lexicon aller Wissenschafften und Künste", 1731–1754, Bd 59 (Wor-Wuq), cf entries for [*Wüste* and *Wüstung*](https://www.zedler-lexikon.de/index.html?c=blaettern&seitenzahl=718&bandnummer=59&view=150&l=de)</sub>

[Regional example for Laide.](https://www.freiepresse.de/zwickau/hohenstein-ernstthal/an-voigtlaide-ist-der-graf-schuld-artikel9863643)

> ***[Lehde:](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL03367#XGL03367)***
>   wüst liegendes stück land; aus dem niederdeutschen bis ins östl. mitteldeutsch vorgedrungenes wort, niederl. leeghde vallis, locus humilis (Kilian), später leegte und laagte niedrig gelegene fläche, niederung; niederd. legte niederung, eichwald (niederd. sprichw. 89b); neufries. leegte, laagte Epkema wb. 264; nordfr. dat läiged, läiget die niederung Bendsen 8; ob auch ein von Dietrich in Haupts zeitschr. 13, 28 aufgewiesenes ags. læð gut, grund und boden hierher gehört, ist zweifelhaft. das stammwort ist das sp. 58 aufgeführte läg, niederd. leeg und laag niedrig, dessen guttural in der ins hochdeutsche gekommenen form lehde schwand, in einer nebenform leide sich vocalisirte. läden heiszen bei den landgütern, wüst liegende aber doch brauchbare plätze. Frisch 1, 563b; laite, leide oder leede, heiszt ein ungeschlachtes wüstes und ungebaut - liegendes stücke land, welches keinen nutzen trägt. oecon. lex. (1731) 1358; ledden oder lehden heiszen die wüsten triftrasen und anger an hohen orten vor denen hölzern; welche ledden mit kurzen, scharfen magern gras und grind unter einander überzogen sind. Heppe leithund 90; das thal verbreitet sich und alle leden sind wo möglich zum feldbau umgearbeitet. Göthe 43, 147;
>   Vandaliciens versengte leeden. 
>   Gökingk 3, 113.
>
> ***[ÖDUNG:](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GO00856#XGO00856)*** f. öde liegender, unfruchtbarer und unbebauter landfleck, verwüstete oder verlassene ortschaft; synon. mit wüstung,

Further, the words ***[Ödung](http://www.zeno.org/Meyers-1905/A/%C3%96dung)*** and ***[Elende](http://www.zeno.org/Meyers-1905/A/Elende)*** are also synonyms.

Interestingly, the word [*Wüste*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/W%C3%BCste) has now commonly a much narrower meaning: a *tree-less* desert being the primarily understood meaning.

## What *is* the word for …

Since the middle ages at least three new single words were coined for closely related concepts or geographically close to village lands:

For the planned '[re-forestation'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforestation): ***[Aufforstung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufforstung)*** meaning not only management of existing forests but also their [re-expansion.](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/bayern/leopoldsreut-im-bayerischen-wald-das-verschwundene-dorf-1.1598823)

For less economically reforestation but planned restoration of land: **[*Renaturierung*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_restoration).** ([Example](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogelsang_(Zehdenick)))

And the absolutely unplanned and often seen as undesirable creeping back of large plants into formerly cultivated lands: **[*Verbuschung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbuschung)**. *Busch* being the intermediary phase of bushes before trees take over in *Verwaldung*. ([Example](https://www.garrey.de/chronik/zur-geschichte-unserer-d%C3%B6rfer/))

And while *Wüstung* as a *terminus technicus* is still widely in use, general understanding of the very word may be somewhat limited now and in conversational language it will probably feel a bit archaic.

But all alternatives, including ***verwaldet*** and ***verwildert*** [are in contemporary use.](https://www.zeit.de/2001/20/Elfenbein_fuer_Brandenburg)

To take a well known modern example: Chernobyl and Pripyat are each a *Wüstung* (the places are ghost towns; most would probably now say *Geisterstadt*) and the places *verwalden* or *verwildern* (meaning nature takes back over, and the trees have a glowing future there ;) ). Both places are now 'a bit' *verwüstet*, meaning mainly in large parts destroyed. It's only 'a bit' as there are from a short distance still many big buildings seen standing. Once these crumble as well, the places will be unequivocally and also in modern parlance be *verwüstet*.

As a newspaper put it to describe such a *Wüstung* near Shanghai:

> [Ein Dorf in China ***versinkt*** völlig im Grünen.](https://www.welt.de/reise/article143077700/Ein-Dorf-in-China-versinkt-voellig-im-Gruenen.html)
>   Verwunschen, verlassen, [***verwildert***](https://www.welt.de/reise/Fern/gallery166527960/Dieses-chinesische-Dorf-versinkt-vollends-im-Gruenen.html): Ein altes Fischerdorf auf einem Archipel vor Shanghai wird vollkommen von der Natur eingenommen.

Comment: How would you thus describe the situation arising around Chernobyl, where the humans have left but the forest still grows and natures takes back the places the men used to occupy. Would you also call that a "Wüstung"?